# Redmine installation on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, redmine

I've been following this installation guide for Redmine http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall. Everything went smoothly until step 5 in which I have to run

```
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
```

Then I got this error

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 0x0009): dependent dylib 'libssl.1.0.0.dylib' not found for '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle' - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/Users/dongphan/Desktop/redmine-3.4.11/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dongphan/Desktop/redmine-3.4.11/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/Users/dongphan/Desktop/redmine-3.4.11/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Seems like libssl.1.0.0.dylib is not found, what should I do to resolve this?

Comment: You need to install mysql development packages for osx...

Comment: Hi, I had mysql development installed. But I figured later that I did not have the path setup...That solved my problem.