# Why am I getting this error `An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2)...` even though mysql is installed and the gem exists?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, redmine, mysql2

I have been racking my brain for days on this, and googling.  I have tried several options on Stackoverflow without success. Most suggestions are to `brew install mysql`, which has already been done.

I have transfered a rails(redmine) web-app via FTP. I am in the root directory of the app. Running any `rails`(such as `rails --version`) command results in an error ending in:

```
[...]
Could not find mysql2-0.5.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

As per the suggestion in the message, i run `bundle install`, and get the familiar error including:

```
[...]
Fetching mysql2 0.5.2
Installing mysql2 0.5.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
[...]
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

As per the suggestion in the message, I run `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/frontwalkermalmo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/CHANGELOG.md
```

For certainty, I run `sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`, which yields the some error message which includes:

```
[...]
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/[USER]/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/[USER]/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/gem_make.out
```

Running `mysql --version` yields:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.43, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

---

### # ADDITIONAL INFO #

I have a wordpress site working fine in a directory, using MAMP and a mysql server.

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Servertyp: MySQL
- Server connection: SSL is not being used Dokumentation
- Serverversion: 5.7.26 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- Protokollversion: 10
- Användare: root@localhost
- Serverns teckenuppsättning: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Question [1]: Is this causing any issues why I can't install the mysql2 gem?

Also, when in the Redmine project app root directory, running `mysqlserverinfo` give me this: `zsh: command not found: mysqlserverinfo`.

Question [2]: Does this help diagnos the issue?

Also-also, this is the output from `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin:/Users/[USER_ACCT]/.rbenv/shims:/Users/[USER_ACCT]/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: You must install mysql development libs for osx as well.

Comment: Hello @AleksandarPavić , and thanks for your comment.  I am not certain how you mean to set up dev libs.  I have also updated the question for some additional observations

Comment: Check comments on another same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811606/redmine-installation-on-macos-mojave-10-14-6?noredirect=1#comment102140129_57811606